# Golang Alphabetic representation of a number

Tags: string, go, type-conversion, character

Is there an easy way to convert a number to a letter?

For example,
 `3` => `"C"` and `23` => `"W"`?

Comment: two options - create an array of all the letters and get it's index+1 from an array. Second - use ascii table and subtract needed number.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

For simplicity range check is omitted from below solutions.
They all can be tried on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/dzO0kdJWJW).

#### Number -> `rune`

Simply add the number to the const `'A' - 1` so adding `1` to this you get `'A'`, adding `2` you get `'B'` etc.:

```
func toChar(i int) rune {
    return rune('A' - 1 + i)
}
```

Testing it:

```
for _, i := range []int{1, 2, 23, 26} {
    fmt.Printf("%d %q\n", i, toChar(i))
}
```

Output:

```
1 'A'
2 'B'
23 'W'
26 'Z'
```

#### Number -> `string`

Or if you want it as a `string`:

```
func toCharStr(i int) string {
    return string('A' - 1 + i)
}
```

Output:

```
1 "A"
2 "B"
23 "W"
26 "Z"
```

This last one (converting a number to `string`) is documented in the [Spec: Conversions to and from a string type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions_to_and_from_a_string_type):

> Converting a signed or unsigned integer value to a string type yields a string containing the UTF-8 representation of the integer.

#### Number -> `string` (cached)

If you need to do this a lot of times, it is profitable to store the `strings` in an array for example, and just return the `string` from that:

```
var arr = [...]string{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M",
    "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"}

func toCharStrArr(i int) string {
    return arr[i-1]
}
```

Note: a slice (instead of the array) would also be fine.

Note #2: you may improve this if you add a dummy first character so you don't have to subtract `1` from `i`:

```
var arr = [...]string{".", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M",
    "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"}

func toCharStrArr(i int) string { return arr[i] }
```

#### Number -> `string` (slicing a `string` constant)

Also another interesting solution:

```
const abc = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

func toCharStrConst(i int) string {
    return abc[i-1 : i]
}
```

Slicing a `string` is efficient: the new `string` will share the backing array (it can be done because `string`s are immutable).

Comment: Might be a dumb question but how did you know that you could add a number to a constant character ( "A" ) to navigate the characters?  Is this something in most languages, go specific, or rune specific?  Never messed with rune() before...

Comment: @afreeland `rune` in Go is an alias for `int32`. If you have a constant like `'A'`, that is equivalent to a value `65`. The types `rune` and `int32` are one and the same, completely interchangable. So when you write `'A' + 1`, it's the same as if you'd write `65 + 1`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for breaking it down a little further for me...I feel much better now =)

Answer (score 6):

If you need not a rune, but a string and also more than one character for e.g. excel column

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func IntToLetters(number int32) (letters string){
    number--
    if firstLetter := number/26; firstLetter >0{
        letters += IntToLetters(firstLetter)
        letters += string('A' + number%26)
    } else {
        letters += string('A' + number)
    }
        
    return 
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(IntToLetters(1))// print A
    fmt.Println(IntToLetters(26))// print Z
    fmt.Println(IntToLetters(27))// print AA
    fmt.Println(IntToLetters(1999))// print BXW
}
```

preview here: https://play.golang.org/p/GAWebM_QCKi

I made also package with this: https://github.com/arturwwl/gointtoletters

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution would be

```
func stringValueOf(i int) string {
   var foo = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
   return string(foo[i-1])
}
```

Hope this will help you to solve your problem. Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to represent a number bigger than 26(Z), this is the simplest solution. Give a try.

```
func convertToAlphabetic(n int) string {
    result := ""
    for n > 0 {
        mod := (n - 1) % 26
        result = string('A'+mod) + result
        n = (n - mod) / 26
    }
    return result
}
```

Example results:

- 3: C
- 32: AF
- 876: AGR