# How to find the next greater string in alphabetical order in Golang?

Tags: string, go

eg: abc**d** -> abc**e** ,  qwe**r** -> qwe**s** etc

my_string := "abcd"

How can I get my_string to have "abce" ?

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36803999/golang-alphabetic-representation-of-a-number

Answer (score 2):

Logically: 
Look at the last letter. If its not z, increment it by one. If it is z, set it to a, then look at the second to last letter. If its not z, increment it by 1. If it is z, set it to a and look at the third to last letter.... and so on

Try and figure out the code your self, this ones actually kind of fun. If you want the code just reply and I'll work it out

Answer (score 1):

as @Mauricio said,parse characters in reverse order.increment a character if it is not 'z'.if all characters are 'z' then replace the first 'z' with 'aa'.

[go playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/A7rIp9Kx7B)