# How to get the equivalent number of character in the alphabetical table in golang

Tags: go

How to get the equivalent number of a character in the alphabetical table in golang
E.g A ==> 1 , B ==> 2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Golang Alphabetic representation of a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36803999/golang-alphabetic-representation-of-a-number)

Comment: No, I saw that too but that's not what I'm looking for. the solution showed there converts from Number to Character  @jakub

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
func f(in rune) int {
  return int(in-'A'+1)
}
```

Ideally you should add some bounds checking to make sure input is in the expected range.

Comment: Your answer is amazing!

Answer (score 2):

You could just get the ascii code for each letter and then subtract 64 from each one (since 65 is ascii A).

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    numeral := alphaNum('B')
    fmt.Println(numeral)
}

func alphaNum(letter rune) int {
    char := int(letter)
    char -= 64
    return char
}
```

I've linked my example into the Go Playground:https://play.golang.org/p/x2NH0XFyc9M

Of course, there's a jump when you go to lowercase letters (since ascii jumps). If that matters, you'll need to account for that with another offset for lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

```
func toNum(c rune) byte {
    return byte(c) - byte('A') + 1
}
func main() {
    fmt.Print(toNum('A'))
    fmt.Print(toNum('B'))
    fmt.Print(toNum('C'))
}
```

The result is:
123